# Are API calls like DescribeTags on EC2 free?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to find information about the cost of API calls like `DescribeTags` on EC2 and I cannot find any reliable info about the pricing of it.

Is it free to call `DescribeTags` etc. from an EC2 instance?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no price for calling API interactions to describe or list resources across the AWS platform.

Generally the costs are associated with the resources in AWS itself such as creating an EC2 instance, reading an object in Amazon S3 etc.

As an exception some functionality within billing has additional pricing for functionality such as hourly based pricing. Other than this you're fine to refresh your console.

Comment: Is there a help topic that explains this or it's meant to be implicit?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no documentation that states pricing. The costs associated are generally not with the API calls, but more with the resources that are created or accessed. :)